# How do Java generic parameters work in methods that are overriden?

Tags: java, generics

I have two classes,

### A.java

```
public abstract class A {
    @Override
    public abstract <T extends A> T add();

    @Override
    public abstract <T extends A> T addWithParam(T param);
}
```

### B.java

```
public class B extends A {
    @Override
    public B add() {...}

    @Override
    public B addWithParam(B param) {...}
}
```

The `add()` method compiles, but the `addWithParam` produces an error, saying that addWithParam(B) must override a method in one of the higher classes (A in this scenario). A fix would be to lose the override annotation altogether, but my intentions are to force the user into overriding the method in class `B` and to return an object of type `B`.

I could only think of two ways to work around this. The first solution would be to set the return type from the generic type `T` to `A`. This would then allow me to return type `A`, however the user would then have to cast the return result from `B.addWithParam(B)` into type B, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

The other solution would be to change the visibility of the abstract methods from public to protected (in `A.java`). Adding onto the previously mentioned solution where I change the return type to `A`, the inheriting class of `A` creates a method that returns `(B) B.addWithParam(B param)` (remember `B.addWithParam(B param)` returns type `A` as specified by the super class).

**So the question here is**, why is the original error produced? Am I just writing the code incorrectly, or does Java directly not support what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: The immediate reason for the compiler error is that in the abstract class, at runtime, the `addWithParam()` method takes an `Object` as input, and also returns an `Object`.  In your overrided version (which doesn't really override in practice), you are taking a concrete `B` type as input, and then also returning a `B` type.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: A counterexample: Consider the situation where `A` is declared as `class A<T>` and the method is `T addWithParam(T param)`, and `B` is declared as `class B extends A<B>` and `B`'s `addWithParam` is `B addWithParam(B param)`. Your premise applies to this situation too -- at runtime, `A`'s `addWithParam` takes an `Object` and returns an `Object` and in the overriding version, it takes a `B` and returns a `B` -- so according to your logic, it should be invalid. Yet this case is perfectly valid and overrides correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public abstract <T extends A> T add();
```

What this method declaration means is that for any object `a` of type `A` or a subtype, you can call the method `a.add()` and get back any subtype of `A` the *caller* wants.  So if you have `class B extends A` and `class C extends A`, what you have just told Java is that the following should work:

```
C c = myB.add();
```

That's not what you mean.  Trust me.

```
public abstract A add();
```

would mean that calling `add()` on any `A` would at least get you an `A` back, and that subtypes of `A` can specify in more detail the exact type they get back, so you could write

```
class B extends A {
   public B add() { ... }
}
```

That's a bit more reasonable.  What this *doesn't* let you do is specify that the `addWithParam` method will only accept a `B`, not another `A` type.

There is *not* any way to force a subclass to return instances of its own type.  There are various hacks and hints people use to enforce this to varying degrees of effectiveness, such as:

```
class A<T extends A> {
  abstract T add();
  abstract T addWithParam(T t);
}
class B extends A<B> {
  B add() { ... }
  B addWithParam(B b) { ... }
}
```

and this at least does what you were trying to do.  What it won't do is prevent someone from writing `class C extends A<B>`.

Comment: I agree with your answer, but I wouldn't call it a hack what you described as the working solution. When we write the interface/class, we are stating that whatever you put in place of the generic type, will be returned in that method. If I choose to put `xyz` as generic type, I would expect to get that returned from such method.

Comment: I consider it a hack precisely because it doesn't guarantee that `T` is actually the "self" type; like I said, you could still write `C extends A<B>`, which violates the intent of the design.

Comment: I agree that it is not possible to enforce having the same class as the generic type as asked in the question, but with the knowledge of the constraints/restriction in java framework, nobody will be surprised with the case of `class C extends A<B>`. Even though it may not make sense in all cases.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I'm thinking about changing the super return type to just `A`, but it'd lead me to the issue of having someone write `C.addWithParam(A)` return something of type `B`. Either way, both solutions would end up relying on the user for returning the intended types. Thanks again!